# Run Odoo11 server always in CentOS7 vps

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, centos7, odoo-11

I successfully installed [Odoo11](https://www.odoo.com) from source(Github) on CentOS7 and it works fine.

I run Odoo server by following command every time and I want to keep it running forever though the server restarts.

```
./odoo-bin --addons-path=addons,../mymodules --db-filter=mydb$
```

Please confirm again I didn't install by package installers.

I'm sure there should be a smart way and I'm looking forward to your help.

Comment: You can use process control sytem program like supervisor